# How to test if all items in a column are identical

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program that needs to check if the values in each column of a two-dimensional array are equal. The number of columns is also static at five.

Currently I have an `if` statement that iterates from column to column and compares all of the values in that column in one giant check:

```
if column[0][i] == column[1][i] && column[0][i] == column[2][i]
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't intend for the confusion. The array creates a 5x5 game board. The rows refers to each individual array and the columns refers to the nth digit in each of the arrays.

Comment: Your code looks like you're actually comparing each value in a "row"—although which are the "columns" and which are the "rows" is debatable. Can you clarify with a brief example of what your array looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing, I think because in most code I've come across that represents a structure with rows and columns using arrays, the "outer" array represents the rows and the "inner" arrays represent the columns. For example:

```
arr = [ [ a, b ],
        [ x, y ] ]
```

In the usual model, (`a`, `b`) is "row" 0, and (`x`, `y`) is row 1. That makes (`a`, `x`) column 0 and (`b`, `y`) column 1.

But your code suggests that your structure is inverted, with row 0 being (`a`, `x`) and row 1 being  (`b`, `y`), which makes (`a`, `b`) column 0 and (`x`, `y`) column 1, so I'll answer it that way. If we want every value in a column to be equal to every value in the same column (i.e. `a == b && x == y`), then it's pretty easy. Suppose we have the following data:

```
arr = [ [ 10, 10, 10, 10 ],  # <-- Column 0
        [ 11, 11, 11, 11 ],  # <-- Column 1
        [ 12,  0, 12, 12 ] ] # <-- Column 2
```

To check if every value in "column" 0 is equal to every other value in column 0, we could do this:

```
arr[0].all? {|item| item == arr[0][0] } # => true
```

This just compares every item in the column to the first item `arr[0][0]` and returns `false` as soon as it finds one that isn't equal (or `true` if it doesn't).

In order to do this for the every "row", we can wrap the first [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) in another:

```
arr.all? do |sub_arr|
  sub_arr.all? {|item| item == sub_arr.first }
end
# => false
```

---

**Edit:** If your array looks instead like this:

```
arr = [ [ 10, 11, 12 ],
        [ 10, 11,  0 ],
        [ 10, 11, 12 ],
        [ 10, 11, 12 ] ]
#          │   │   └─ Column 2
#          │   └─ Column 1
#          └─ Column 0
```

One way to solve it would be this:

```
first_row, *rest = arr

rest.all? do |row|
  row.each_with_index.all? do |item, col_idx|
    row[col_idx] == first_row[col_idx]
  end
end
```

The first line assigns the first row to `first_row` and the rest of the rows to `rest`. Then for each row in `rest` we use `all?` to compare each item to the corresponding item in `first_row`.

P.S. Another way to solve it would be this:

```
arr.transpose.all? {|row| row.uniq.size == 1 }
```

[`Array#transpose`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-transpose) just swaps the rows and columns (i.e. turning `[[a,b],[x,y]]` into `[[a,x],[b,y]]`), and then in `all?` we use count the unique values in each "column" (which is now a row). If there's more than one unique value we know they're not all equal. Of course, this has a lot more overhead: Both `transpose` and `uniq` iterate over every value and return a new array, whereas the method above stops as soon as it finds any value that doesn't match. But given only 25 items it might not be so bad, depending on how often you need it to run.

P.P.S. I was curious how much better the first method performs than the second. You can see the code and the result here: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/7168af45c5fa5fb4ddd3 Because the first method "short-circuits"—i.e. it stops as soon as it finds a "wrong" value—it gets faster as the probability of a "wrong" value increases. With a 33% chance of any row having a wrong value, the first method performs 33% faster than the second. With a 75% chance, the first performs 80% faster than the second. I realize that's more information than you require, but I found it interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that question really poorly, you were actually correct in your first assumption that (a,x) and (b,y) are the columns.